# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar un carácter por otro en un texto sin utilizar .replace?

Tags: java, string

El problema es que debo crear un subprograma que cambie los siguientes simbolos por las letras utilizar .replace lo empeze para que lea toda la frase pero nose como hacer para que si detecta el 4 lo cambie por una A alguien me ayuda? Igual mi codigo es una parida estoy empezando no sean duros ajja.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public static String descifrarLenguajeHacker(String pText) {
    char a;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < pText.length() ; i++) {   
            a = pText.charAt(i);
        }
        
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Amigo, no edites el codigo para no dejar nada.

Comment: Por favor no generes más trabajo a los otros usuarios vandalizando tu publicación. Por política de SE, cualquier clase de vandalismo será revertido. Si queres saber más sobre cómo eliminar una publicación, considera mirar: [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1033/).

Comment: @AAG por que has vuelto a editar la pregunta?

Answer (score 1):

Podes utilizar un bucle y la clase StringBuilder. La clase StringBuilder te permite construir y modificar cadenas de manera eficiente agregando o eliminando caracteres.

Acá te dejo un ejemplo con parte de tu código:

```
public static String descifrarLenguajeHacker(String pText) {
    char a;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < pText.length(); i++) {
        a = pText.charAt(i);
        if (a == 'a') {
            sb.append('z');
        } else {
            sb.append(a);
        }
    }
    
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Este código recorrerá los caracteres en el pText de entrada y va a verificar si el carácter es una 'a'. Si es así, agregará una 'z' al objeto StringBuilder. Si no, agregará el carácter original. Al final, devolverá la cadena modificada llamando al método toString() en el objeto StringBuilder.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda compañero!