# ¿Como cambiar un caracter por otro?

Tags: java, string

Estoy haciendo un codigo que si el texto es A4 lo cambie a AA y estoy usando el stringbuilder nose que es lo que tengo mal alguien me dice que hice mal y si me lo puede explicar porfavor?

```
public static void main(String.) {
        

        
        String texto = "A4";
            
    
                    
        char a;
                 
            StringBuilder c= new StringBuilder();
            
            for (int i = 0; i < texto.length(); i++) {
                a = texto.charAt(i);
                
                    
                    if (a == '4') {
                        c.append('a');}
                     {
                        c.append(a);}
            }
            
                     
                    System.out.println(texto());    
            }
}
```

Comment: ¿El único objetivo de la función es modificar A4 por AA? Hay más casos que necesitas modificar o sólo A4?

Comment: en un futuro lo intentare diseñar para una frase entera

Comment: Por favor, no [repitas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/574652/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-cambiar-un-car%c3%a1cter-por-otro-en-un-texto-sin-utilizar-replace) preguntas, puedes editar la original las veces que sea necesario. Saludos

Comment: ¿Por qué no empleas .replace? Aunque sea una frase completa, con este código realizas lo mismo pero de una formas más ineficiente.

Comment: esque este es otro codigo que e creado para tenerlo mas claro ya que no consigo que cambie el caracter

Comment: estas imprimiedo la variable texto,cuando deberias imprimir la variable Cambiarpalabra

Comment: – Brahim Khallota, quiero usar el stringBuild se podria?

Comment: Dramaturgo es verdad ya lo cambie y funciona muchas gracias

Comment: para sustituir mas caracteres como seria, es decir que el 4sea una a y el 5 una b? porque si pongo mas if sale raro.

Answer (score 0):

¿Es necesario usar `StringBuilder`? Porque podríamos usar el método `replace` del `String` y ya

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String texto = "A4";
    
    texto = texto.replace('4', 'A');
    
    System.out.println(texto); // resultado: AA
}
```

Comment: que no string builder tiene tambien un metodo replace?

Answer (score -1):

creo que podrías usar un map para lo que necesitas:

```
Map <String, String> mapaDeCaracteres = new TreeMap<>();
```

Dado que la cantidad de pares de datos es grande, yo optaría por rellenarlo con un bucle, usando dos arrays con los datos, ejemplo:

```
 String arrayLetraOriginal[] = { "a", "b", "c" };
 String arrayLetraDeReemplazo[] = { "z", "k", "m" };

 for( int i = 0; i < arrayLetraOriginal.length; i++ ) {
    mapaDeCaracteres.put( arrayLetraOriginal[ i ], arrayLetraDeReemplazo[ i ] );
 }
```

Luego solo resta pedirle al map el caracter de reemplazo:

```
String letraNueva = mapaDeCaracteres.get( "a" );
```

que nos devuelve "z".

Si necesitas más info sobre "Map", puedes buscar en
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/map-interface-java-examples/

Espero que te funcione, aunque sería más fácil, si pusieras un ejemplo de lo que recibe la función y lo que se espera de ella.